# If a 100,000 ton container ship slams into a bridge at 8.6 knots how much energy was moved into the pylon and at what rate of transfer speed?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, mass-energy, rigid-body-dynamics

*Edit: the entire question is in the title, the answer should be an amount of energy and a value of energy transfer in some unit, but not knowing enough about physics I don’t know what the appropriate unit would be which is what prompted the explanation below… I am quite surprised by the responses here but I am most of all stumped by how this is not considered a focused question*

Original subtext:

Forgive me for not knowing what unit of measurement would represent how fast all that energy moved into the bridge but let’s assume the ship came to a full stop in a few seconds without worrying about what might be lost into the hull crumbling, etc

For extra charm perhaps someone could tell me how many times I would have to hit a cue ball in 9-ball to equal the amount of energy transferred between them? what about in gallons of gasoline? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest rewriting this question or rethinking it, given the circumstances of the loss of life that happened in Maryland

Comment: @lamplamp it might well have been motivated by that incident.

Comment: Asking this after a large scale tragedy involving these exact circumstance is extremely tasteless.

Comment: *"For extra charm..."* For extra charm, please see these guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should pose a single, coherent, answerable question. This is not a place where you just run your mouth.

Comment: Wow I am really surprised by the negative response to this question, did I just post it in the wrong forum? I debated posting it in engineering but figured physics would have given more interesting answers… back in my day scientific curiosities around current events were appreciated rather than scorned…

Comment: @MetaGuru Scientific curiosity does not trump human feelings. Can you understand why some people will find the framing of your question insensitive, given that lives were lost in this tragedy ?

Comment: @MetaGuru the physics of your main question about energy released is not inappropriate, and I am sure is being asked in many forums without any objections. 
But your references to "extra charm" and "hit a cue ball in 9-ball" suggest a levity that many readers would find insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are concerned only with the energy involved in the impact you needn't worry about the time required for the vessel to come to a stop, rather, using the work energy theorem one can calculate the energy change based on the 8.6 knots speed data. For example choosing the ship as the system and employing SI units:
$$W=\Delta E\implies \Delta E=-{1\over 2}Mv^2=-{1\over 2}(8.88\times 10^7\text{kg})(4.42\text{m/s})^2=-8.67\times 10^8 J.$$
Here the minus sign merely indicates that the energy was transferred away from the ship. Given that a gallon of gasoline contains approximately $120$ million Joules of energy, then the exchange of energy amounts to some $7.23$ gallons of gasoline.

My condolences go out to any and all who have lost loved ones in the terrible tragedy.

Comment: interesting, for some reason I expected it to be a lot higher, it’s hard to believe that 7.3 gallons of fuel contains enough energy to incapacitate that bridge

Comment: @MetaGuru Yes, the result is surprising. Gasoline is terribly energetic. However, consider that the energy in the gasoline would have to be released all at once; something that is in practice almost impossible, under most conditions, 7 gallons of gas would just make a big fireball, it would not spontaneously convert itself to energy all at once.